# Is it possible to add “Auto Filter” in SSRS reports exported Excel Output file?

Tags: reporting-services, filter, ssrs-grouping, autofilter

Currently I am working in project, where we are migrating all the Excel reports (Behind logic in **VBA** code) to **SSRS** reports. I have to enable **AUTO FILTER** for the excel reports generated from **SSRS**. Can you please help on this

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to figure out how to do this as well. So far I have the following VBA to add an auto-filter to all sheets on row 1:

```vb
Sub FilterLoop()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Select
        Range("A1").AutoFilter
    Next I
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

It is less than ideal, but I have added this to my `PERSONAL` workbook so that I can just run it when I generate a new report. I hope this helps, and if I figure out something better, I'll post again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too and I think it is not possible.

The Excel export is primarily a layout renderer. It replicates the layout of the rendered report as closely as possible. There are differences and different limitations in Excel, so not everything is working.
The AutoFilter is not supported, you cannot add it automatically to the exported file.

Excel does not support interactive sort either.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs#a-nameinteractivitya-interactivity

In my case, I have to open the generated file in c# and add the filter there.